# xpath selecting sibling from parent

Tags: xpath

I'm new to xpath, so please forgive me. I have multiple autocompletes that use tokens. I'm trying to select child `<p>` based on text `Some Text 1` from parent `div.title=title` and get the sibling `span.remove-token`.

Example

```
<div title="title">
    <ul class="token-list">
        <li class="input-token"
            <p>Some Text 1</p>
            <span class="remove-token">x</span>
        </li>
        <li class="input-token"
            <p>Some Text 2</p>
            <span class="remove-token">x</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

What I've attempted

```
String path = "//div[contains(@title, 'title')]/p[text()="Some Text 1"]/following-sibling::span]";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use**:

```
//div[@title = 'title']//li/p[. = 'Some Text 1']/following-sibling::span[1]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
//div[contains(@title,'title')]//p[text()="Some Text 1"]/following-sibling::span
```

There were two tiny mistakes:

1. there was an unnecessary `]` at the end of the expression
2. the `p` element is not a direct child of the `div`, so you must search all descendants